# Scheme - turn each element of a list into a list (list of lists)

Tags: scheme

I have list in scheme: `(3 4 2)` and I want to make it a list of lists, i.e: `((3) (4) (2))`, How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize the `map` function, e.g. `(map list '(3 4 5))`, which is the bread and butter of all list manipulation. It's equivalent to a list comprehension in python, or a for loop in java.

for the record:

You can also use `reduce` and `filter` for more complicate list-manipulation tasks. You do not really need anything else, besides maybe `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it Little Schemer style with only basic functions you could create something like this:

`(define make-list

..(lambda (lat)

....(cond

......((null? lat) (quote()))

......(else (cons (cons (car lat) (quote()))

..................(make-list (cdr lat))))))))`